# Do we have a name for the 3-Point-Distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

- The Two-Point-Distribution is also known as the *Bernoulli Distribution* and is quite prominent.
- Would imagine a Three-Point-Distribution to be fairly common as well (say probabilities of not just going up or down, but going down, staying neutral or going up); however it does not seems to be the case.
- Is there a name for the *3-Point Distribution* or more generically *$n$-Point Distribution*?

Comment: Not sure there is a _name_ for the 1-trial case, but the repeated case is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution

Comment: @antkam Good comment. I guess it does give somewhat of a notational boundary -- worst case can refer to it as multinomial with parameter $\boldsymbol{\theta} = (n=1, k=3)$, but still, would imagine it being special enough to get its own name.

Comment: With apologies to the great historical Bernoulli family...  perhaps Multinoulli?  Just kidding ;)

Comment: @antkam If no official name is flagged up, I am calling it Trinoulli.